# Is there a generic way to solve cubic inequalities?

Tags: inequality, cubics

Hi Pardon me if it has already been asked. I could not find any material on math-stack, hence asked this question!
   I have a cubic inequality of the form,
\begin{equation}
-a_1x^3+a_2x^2+a_3x+a_4<0
\end{equation}
Is there a generic way to solve such cubic inequality? I am preferably looking for a scenario where this will have only one real root.

Comment: Yes, there is a cubic formula much like the quadratic formula but much longer.

Comment: You can see the cubic discriminant to find the cases where there is only one real root.